# Cancel unload window javascript without confirm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I want prevent the client leave the page in my asp.net application
whithout saving ,the folowing code get option to leave the page without saving by click 'Ok'
in the confirm.
override confirm function not work in my browser(ie8)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    IsSaved = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                    return IsSaved ;            } 
</script>
```

where client save the data:

```
IsSaved  = true;
```

EDIT:
 I want to disable click on 'ok' button too.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is...

Comment: I heve to prevent click 'ok' in confirm too, disable leaving the page without saving

Answer (score 4):

You can’t override the confirmation function, because it’s a confirmation function. If a browser wouldn’t let the user close a page just because the page didn’t want to be closed, that would be a horrible security flaw.

Confirm like everyone else. And auto-save too.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return !isSaved && "You have unsaved (stuff). Are you sure you want to quit?";
};
```

Comment: I heve to prevent click 'ok' in confirm too, disable leaving the page without saving

Comment: @mich Like he said, that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I created a library I could include in all my web sites easily, so that this functionality would be easily accessible.

Put this class in a new C# class library project, so you can reference it from your other projects (web sites).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyNameSpace.ConfirmLeavePageScript
    {
    [DefaultProperty("TextToDisplay")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:ServerControl1 runat=server></{0}:ServerControl1>")]
    public class ConfirmLeavePageScript : WebControl
        {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string TextToDisplay
            {
            get
                {
                String s = (String)ViewState["TextToDisplay"];
                return ((s == null) ? "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" : s);
                }

            set
                {
                ViewState["TextToDisplay"] = value;
                }
            }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
            {
            string script = @"

            <script type='text/javascript'>
    var confirmOnPageExit = function (e)
    {
        // If we haven't been passed the event get the window.event
        e = e || window.event;

        var message = '" + TextToDisplay + @"';
        if(typeof ConfirmLeavePageMessage != 'undefined') //give client side the opportunity to overwrite the message instead of using message from ViewState.
            {
            message=ConfirmLeavePageMessage;
            }

        // For IE6-8 and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e)
        {
            e.returnValue = message;
        }

        // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
        return message;
    };

    function EnableConfirmOnPageExit()
        {
        // Turn it on - assign the function that returns the string
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmOnPageExit;
        }


function DisableConfirmOnPageExit()
        {
    // Turn it off - remove the function entirely
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
</script>

            ";
            output.Write(script);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can register the tag prefix in your web site projects by putting this in your web.config. Make sure your website adds the C# class library project as a reference (put them in the same solution).

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="tna" assembly="ConfirmLeavePage" namespace="MyNameSpace.ConfirmLeavePageScript" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then, put the control in the head of your content pages.

```
<head>
<tna:ConfirmLeavePageScript runat="server" TextToDisplay="Are you sure you want to leave without saving?" />
</head>
```

In your JavaScript functions that detect if changes have been made, call this function:

```
EnableConfirmOnPageExit();
```

You can also do the following (which I think are self explanatory):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
ConfirmLeavePageMessage="new message"; //set a custom message from JavaScript for the confirmation window
DisableConfirmOnPageExit(); //Disables the confirmation window (user can leave page without seeing the confirmation window)
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all that code". The JavaScript function supports new and old browsers. It also makes it possible to modify the displayed message from server side easily, and makes it easily portable between multiple projects.